# UITableViewCell is accepting only longpress

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Facing trouble with `UITableViewCell`.I tried to get the data of selected UITableViewCell. Initially it is working good but after the `UITapGestureRecognizer` its making this trouble. The table i've used is assigned to the one subview even few buttons are not taking the action at first click. I am facing this trouble exactly after adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                            action:@selector(didTapAnywhere:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [self.scrolling addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [self.notesView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

-(void)didTapAnywhere: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {

    [ageview removeFromSuperview];
    [contiView removeFromSuperview];
    [CountryTableview removeFromSuperview];
    [notesView endEditing:YES];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you please post your gesture recogniser code also here

Comment: Using gesture recognizers with scroll view content is always tricky, that's because scroll views add a delay before it is delivered to the implementing view. Saying that is not clear to me what and you want to achieve.

Comment: i just need to get the text if selected cell

Comment: Why do you need to add a gesture rec, cell can be in a selected state by default

Comment: i need it for another purpose not for this one... but after adding gesturerec its making problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Tap Guesture is cancelling the touch guesture to your cell and your Buttons, make sure that the view to which you are assigning a tap guesture does not overlap the buttons which would result in cancellation of touch events

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement delegate method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    UIView *view = (UIView *)touch.view;
    if([view isKindOfClass:[<YOUR_BUTTON> class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

OR you can give some tag to button like following

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    UIView *view = (UIView *)touch.view;
    if(view.tag == 10000) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```